# How to Assign Values in a Cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the `PeriodTable` there are three period JAN,FEB,MARCH

Now I want three query like:

```
   SELECT JAN FROM MainTable

   SELECT FEB FROM MAinTable

   SELECT MARCH FROM MAinTable
```

I have declared a cursor and I want to assign `@period` value in a query?

```
DECLARE @period varchar(max),
        @temp varchar(max)
DECLARE @dquery varchar(max)
SET @period=''
    DECLARE Period_Cursor CURSOR For SELECT DISTINCT period FROM dbo.PeriodTable
      OPEN Period_Cursor
      FETCH NEXT FROM Period_Cursor INTO @temp
     WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN

       SET @period=@period+'['+@temp+']'
       SELECT '''+@period+''' FROM MainTable
       FETCH NEXT FROM Period_Cursor INTO @temp
END
    CLOSE Period_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE Period_Cursor
    PRINT (@period)
```

But didn't work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use dynamic sql for this. If you want to select columns dynamically, you need to wrap the whole `SELECT` statement in a dynamic sql and use use table name in a `single-qoutes` and + operator like `'+ @period +'` and finally execute it.

```
Declare @period varchar(max),
      @temp varchar(max)
      DECLARE @dquery varchar(Max)
      set @period=''
       declare Period_Cursor cursor for select distinct period from        dbo.PeriodTable
      open Period_Cursor
      fetch next from Period_Cursor into @temp
     while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
     begin

       set @period=@period+'['+@temp+']'

      set @dquery = 'select '+@period+' from MainTable'
      EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @dquery 

       fetch next from Period_Cursor into @temp
      end
    close Period_Cursor
    Deallocate Period_Cursor
    print(@period)
```